# Fixed light source in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to draw an earth in Matlab with a fixed light source around it,  that way I can observe earth's rotation with dayside and nightside . But now I get stuck on how to use the function `light`.

My Matlab code is as follows:

```
figure
load('topo.mat','topo','topomap1'); 
[x,y,z] = sphere(50);
cla reset
axis square off
props.AmbientStrength = 0.1;
props.DiffuseStrength = 1;
props.SpecularColorReflectance = .5;
props.SpecularExponent = 20;
props.SpecularStrength = 1;
props.FaceColor= 'texture';
props.EdgeColor = 'none';
props.FaceLighting = 'phong';
props.Cdata = topo;
h=surface(x,y,z,props);
h1=light('position',[-1 0 0],'Style','infinite');
% light('position',[-1.5 0.5 -0.5], 'color', [.6 .2 .2]);
  set(gcf,'color',[1 1 1]);
el=0;
for az=0:10:300
  view(az, el)
  drawnow;
end
```

Comment: Have you tried `doc light` and did some of the examples from there?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin : yes, I have tried to use 'doc light', but I am still not able to figure out how to define the "position" property of light in a plot.

Comment: Have a play with `lightm` and then look at the properties that returns.